# IRC Bot Android Studio using PircbotX

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, pircbot

I am coding an IRC Bot using PircbotX library and without android studio it works perfectly.
When I run my application, I got this error in my console:

```
2020-01-07 13:25:20.050 19323-19323/? W/ordwalrus.alit: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-01-07 13:25:21.352 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/ordwalrus.alit: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.353 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/ordwalrus.alit: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.451 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita D/ALITA-DEBUG: Configure new Bot
2020-01-07 13:25:21.552 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2020-01-07 13:25:21.553 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2020-01-07 13:25:21.553 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-01-07 13:25:21.819 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita D/ALITA-DEBUG: Starting bot
2020-01-07 13:25:21.827 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
2020-01-07 13:25:21.827 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
2020-01-07 13:25:21.827 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
2020-01-07 13:25:21.900 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1108)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:235)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at org.pircbotx.PircBotX.startBot(PircBotX.java:181)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at dev.lordwalrus.alita.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.901 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.902 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.902 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.902 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.902 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.902 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.902 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.902 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.903 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.903 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.903 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.903 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.903 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.903 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2020-01-07 13:25:21.903 19323-19323/dev.lordwalrus.alita W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

In my Project Structure, in All Modules section, I have slf4k-api→1.7.13 but I do not understand if this dependency is installed on my workspace or not because in app module section I don't find it.

[My All Modules Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e40uu.jpg)
[My app module section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmZzJ.jpg)

This is my code in main Activity:

```
package dev.lordwalrus.alita;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.pircbotx.Configuration;
import org.pircbotx.PircBotX;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("ALITA-DEBUG", "Configure new Bot");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
                // Set nick of bot
                .setName("alita")
                // Set real name
                .setRealName("alita")
                // IRC server works perfectly without android application
                .addServer("irc.servername.org")
                // Join in IRC channel
                .addAutoJoinChannel("#channel-name")
                // Add listener that will be called on Events
                .addListener(new MyPircBotX())
                // Build configuration
                .buildConfiguration();

        // Create bot with my configuration
        PircBotX bot = new PircBotX(configuration);
        // Connect to the server
        try {
            Log.d("ALITA-DEBUG", "Starting bot");
            bot.startBot();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I got this error when I call bot.startBot() method.

Thank you a lot! Hope you could help me to fix this problem!

Comment: `See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.` have you checked this url?
And the second issue that `startBot()` probably does network calls, so you need to run this command in a background thread or background service.

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply. I have fixed calling startBot() method inside a new Thread. Thank you again!